# Access 2007 How to link a table with multi-value lookup fields

Tags: database, ms-access, linked-list

I have a database with a few multi-valued lookup fields. When i split my database, there is a repeated error that the junction table is not found. I know Access makes shadow tables when you use the lookup wizard. How do i link these tables? 
I tried the following code:

```
Sub refresh()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Name] FROM [MSysObjects] WHERE ([Type] =  6);", dbOpenSnapshot, dbForwardOnly)
    Do While (Not rs.EOF)
        db.TableDefs.Delete rs.Fields("Name").Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

but when I ran it it still gave me the same error message, that the hidden junction table "in this case called "TblAudienceTblProg"" was not found.

Is there any way to get around this or do I have to restructure the whole back end to include the actual junction tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think the multivalued datatype is only really useful when the backend is going to be in SharePoint or you do not plan to split a local database.

Basically what a multivalued field type is is a many to many relationship without the hassle of creating a bridge table yourself.

[Please click here for more information](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/07/18/multivalued_datatypes_access/)

Comment: Yeah. after doing some research I've realize its probably not the best thing to use. The only reason i did it is because the end product wont be split, were just splitting it internally so many people can enter data and QA it at the same time. It should be a better option in the end, but its frustating now. No problem though, for some reason the table links dont seem to need refreshing. We've been entering data for some time now and its worked out fine.